# How to interpret the evolution of accuracy and loss?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am training a neural network using pytorch. here is the code for my model and training loop.

```
class AccidentModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(89, 1600)
        self.act1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1600, 800)
        self.act2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.act3 = nn.Softmax()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(800, 2)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.act1()
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.act2()
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.act3()
        x = self.fc3(X)
        return x

def train(train_dl, model, epochs, losses, accuracies):   
    loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        with tqdm.tqdm(train_dl, unit="batch") as tepoch:  
            for (features, target) in tepoch:               
                tepoch.set_description(f"Epoch {epoch}")
                optimizer.zero_grad() 
                features, target = features.to(get_device()), target.to(get_device())
                output = model(features.float())
                target = target.view(-1)                
                loss = loss_function(output, target)
                loss.backward()  
                optimizer.step()
                output = torch.argmax(output, dim=1)
                correct = (output == target).float().sum()
                accuracy = correct / features.shape[0]
                losses.append(loss)
                accuracies.append(accuracy)
                tepoch.set_postfix(loss=loss.item(), accuracy=accuracy.item())
```

and here is the evolution of the accuracy (orange) and the loss (blue) function:
[image]

My question is if my model is really learning or not? anf how to interpret this graph?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No it's not learning, your loss is not decreasing in this case of classification.

What type of datas are you using ? text ? images ? It might be good to begin with a "classical" architecture according to the task.

You may have to delete your third activation which is not necessary and/or wrongly placed.

There are a lot of guides for beginners online ...